# Can "double" functional dependencies exist?

Tags: relational-database, relation, relational-algebra, functional-dependencies

This is a simple question I have that wasn't covered in my class or notes, and I don't know how to word it well enough to Google search it.

Do "double" functional dependencies exist?

Example:

X->Y and Y->X

Answer (score 1):

In the above case, only one-to-one relationship is allowed. Which means, for every unique, value of X, there will be one unique value of Y and the other way. Like EmployeeID and EmployeeName, but with no 2 employees having same name.

Comment: In other words: yes some dependencies are "bijections" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection. EmployeeName -> EmployeeId is a bit suspect because you might employ two "John Smith"s. Better example: a table with attributes {X, Y} s.t. X is double Y.